# Stop animation *and* prevent complete action from running?

Tags: jquery

I'm fading a background in and out:

```
// in:
$bg.css({'pointerEvents':'auto'}).show()
    .stop(true).animate({ 'opacity': 0.90 }, animTime);

// out:
$bg.css({'pointerEvents':'none'}).stop(true)
    .animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, animTime,function () { $bg.hide(); });
```

The problem happens when I start fading it back in before it finishes fading out; the complete event will fire part way through the fade-in animation and hide the background.

I guess `.stop(true)` doesn't clear the complete event -- is there some way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try `.stop(true,true)`. That will stop the current event as well as remove queued events.

> `.stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )`
>   `clearQueueA` Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.
>   `jumpToEndA` Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.

Comment: Argh! Didn't know it took a 2nd param. Going to try this now. Edit: Actually, I don't want it to skip to the end of the animation. I want it to fade from where-ever it left off, otherwise it will create a jerky animation.

Comment: @mmmshuddup: No. They're triggered by click events. If a person clicks fast they can fire them before the animation finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround:

```
$bg.data('fading',true).css({'pointerEvents':'auto'}).stop(true).show().transition({ 'opacity': 0.90 }, animTime, function () { $bg.data('fading', false); });

$bg.css({'pointerEvents':'none'}).stop(true).transition({ 'opacity': 0 }, animTime,function () {
    if(!$bg.data('fading')) {
        $bg.hide();
    }
});
```